# jQuery Slider handles shifted to left

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have need to use a slider from jQuery and must resize it. Everything looks good, except the handles, shifted to left. I tried css `margin`, `padding`, `right` but it didn't help. Is there some way to correct this?

Bellow you can find what is it like (zoomed 500%) and css code.
[image]

```
.ui-slider {
    background: #1f3e7c;
    border-radius: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
}
.ui-slider-range {
    background: #3366cc;
    border-radius: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
}
.ui-slider .ui-slider-handle {
    background: #dc3912;
    border-radius: 2px 2px 2px 2px;
    width: 3px;
    height: 11px;
}
/* for div that contains slider*/
.rangeSlider {
    color:#0000ff;
    position: absolute;
    width: 30%;
    top: 100%;
    height: 4px;
}
```

**UPDATE:** Please, see below link for details:
https://jsfiddle.net/binary_mind/xnL9b9uq/5/

Comment: Provide the html as well please. A [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) is also handy for us and will get you more responses.

Comment: Handle has default jQuery UI styles already applied to it, remove or adjust `margin-left` to your needs, it usually has to be width / 2 * -1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `jquery-ui.css:753`

There is `margin-left: -.6em;` property for `.ui-slider-horizontal .ui-slider-handle`. 
Change it to `0` and it will be done!